# Send HTTPBody data with restkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I'm using a firefox tool call "Poster" to check that my web service is working. When I POST the request I send a JSON object in the content to send (also call [HTTP body data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_body_data)). 
When I press the POST button the result is fine.
[image]

Now I want to do exactly the same with [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) in objective-c:

```
    NSString *squery = @"{\"Sort\":\"Relevance\",\"DaysToSearch\":0,\"WorkType\":\"\",\"PageSize\":20,\"LastRunCount\":0,\"IndustryCodes\":[\"\"],\"AccountId\":27,\"Experience\":\"\",\"GetResultCount\":0,\"Keywords\":\"iOS\",\"PageIndex\":0,\"DistanceFromLocation\":\"250\",\"SalaryType\":\"\",\"JobQueryId\":\"\",\"JobTitleCodes\":[\"\"]}";

RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectLoaderWithResourcePath:url delegate:performJobQueryHandler];
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
objectLoader.objectMapping = s.jobQueryDataMapper;
objectLoader.HTTPBody = [squery dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[objectLoader send];
```

As a result I get: "An non-fault exception is occured."

In the FireFox extension "Poster" if I use a different mine-type than "application/json", let say "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" I get the same error: "An non-fault exception is occured." 
Is something wrong with objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;   ???

Martin Magakian

Comment: For information the error "An non-fault exception is occured." is the string return by my web service

Comment: Can you debug the web service? If you're getting this message from the web service, it seems like stepping through that code is going to be the quickest way to figure out why the exception is occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I find out.

I activated RestKit debug with

> RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

And I get:

```
2012-02-14 11:55:48 [4048:207] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:318 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://servicestest.foo.com/jobservice/jobservice.svc/json/jobquery>'. HTTP Headers: {
Accept = "application/json";
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: Sort=Relevance&DaysToSearch=0&WorkType=&SalaryType=&LastRunCount=0&IndustryCodes[]=&Experience=&AccountId=0&GetResultCount=0&PageIndex=0&DistanceFromLocation=250&PageSize=20&JobQueryId=&JobTitleCodes[]=.
```

So I think using RKObjectLoader object don't care about objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; because the Content-Type remain "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; instead of "Content-Type" = "application/json";

Do you think it's a bug or the normal behavior ?

Comment: If you think this is an issue you might instead post this over at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues - I imagine your response will be much improved.